# How to make the thymeleaf files appear outside the WEB-INF folder in the server by packaging and server upload?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I have been struggling with bringing Spring Boot to run.

**1. Configuration for deployment**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class IspringerApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(IspringerApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(IspringerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>tempstaff-system</groupId>
    <artifactId>ispringer</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>ispringer</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>iSpringer</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**2. Resource structure with thymeleaf, js, phh, etc.**

[image]

**3. Deployed via terminal in IntelliJ: mvn clean package**

[image]

**4. Uploaded, compressed (zip) and uncompressed in public_html in cpanel**

[image]

All tutorials that I watch the html files are uploaded automatically out of the folders, fit for use. Mime I don't see them and don't know how to bring it to run now.

Could you pls help?

Comment: Ofcourse this won't work. You need to run the application `java -jar <name-of-jar/war>` or deploy it to a tomcat server. Just dropping it into a web-server will not run anything.

Comment: Spring boot already provides you with an embedded tomcat server. I highly recommend you to package your application as JAR given you are using Spring. You will need to find a hosting service which allows you to host java application.

Comment: in cpanel, in file management system there is a ea-tomcat85 folder with a webapp subfolder. Inside it there is an ROOT subfolder.